# Application Skips Code While Debugging, Never Hits Breakpoint?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

When I launch my application in debug mode to try to find why I'm not getting any data returned, I set a breakpoint that is never reached. I call this code when a ReportViewer is loaded. For testing I give it the ID of 9 to return a generic list of data...

```
performanceReportDataList = PerformanceReportData.GetPerformanceReportDataByMilestoneID(9)
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("dsPerformanceReportData", performanceReportDataList))
```

The second line of code is never hit. The application skips the rest of the code in the method and just loads up the ReportViewer completely blank. Now there is some behind the scenes code through a few layers that takes place as the first line is called to fill the generic list. I pass the ID, create a command object and give it the ID as a parameter and call a stored procedure. Running the same thing on the database returns the data just fine, but here's where my code stops....

```
 Public Shared Function GetDataTableUsingReader(ByVal sql As String, Optional ByVal parameterList As List(Of DataParameter) = Nothing, Optional ByVal type As CmdType = CmdType.StoredProcedure) As DataTable
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = CreateCommand(sql, parameterList, type)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cmd.Connection
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) ' Last Line Hit
        End Using
        Return dt
End Function
```

Above is a method in my DAL. It goes to dt.Load() and then doesn't hit any other line of code, it skips right back to the application and loads the ReportViewer form with no data. There's no exception, no nothing. I've seen stuff like this happen before with a classmate back when I was in college, really don't remember what his issue was though. Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: maybe put your breakpoint somewhere just before the 'skip' happens and step-into from there...

Comment: Well on the first line where it attempts to fill the generic list I set a breakpoint and followed from there when I realized it wasn't hitting my original breakpoint. I stepped into all the way to the dt.Load() which is the last line it hits. I hit step-into after that and it gives control back to the GUI and the form pops up.

Comment: Use a try catch finally.  It may be throwing an error that you are not catching.

Comment: Wow, got it. Guess I forgot to wrap one around the loading of the ReportViewer. Funny thing is I would have thought that during debug it would take me right into code and give me an unhandled exception. So amateur not to have even realized this though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that was the answer.
Use a try catch finally. It may be throwing an error that you are not catching.